# How to have a 3D filter for Conv2D in Keras?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

My input images have 8 channels and my output (label) has 1 channel and my CNN in keras is like below:

```py
def set_model(ks1=5, ks2=5, nf1=64, nf2=1):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(nf1, padding="same", kernel_size=(ks1, ks1), 
                     activation='relu', input_shape=(62, 62, 8)))
    model.add(Conv2D(nf2, padding="same", kernel_size=(ks2, ks2), 
                                              activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta())
    return model
```

The filter I have here is the same for all 8 channels. What I would like to have is a 3D filter, something like (8, 5, 5) such that every channel has a separate filter because these channels have not the same importance.

Below is the summary of the model implemented above:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 64)        12864     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 1)         1601      
=================================================================
Total params: 14,465
Trainable params: 14,465
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And when I get the shape of weights for the first layer I have the following results:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights()

len(weights)
2

a = np.array(weights[0]) 
a.shape
(5, 5, 64, 1)
```

And I am wondering where is 8 in the shape of weights of the first layer?

Comment: You are wrong! The kernel of a `Conv2D` layer has `d` number of channels, where `d` is the depth of previous layer. What are the values of `ks1` and `nf1`?

Comment: That's why the first layer has 12864 parameters: `64 * (1 + 8*5*5) = 64 * 201 = 12864`, the one is for the bias parameter. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50700953/2099607) for more info.

Comment: @today , I edited the post so now it has the values for the model's parameters. And when I get the shape of weights for the first layer I get (5, 5, 64, 1), which means I have 64 filters of size (5,5), right? so it is not 3D

Comment: Would you please post the code that you use to get the weights and their shape, as well?

Comment: @today, I updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: You are only storing the weights of last layer (which should be, according to the summary of the model, `(5, 5, 64, 1)`). First initialize weights: `weights = []` and then change the `for` body to: `weights.append(layer.weights)`. Then everything would be as expected.

Comment: @today, thanks for your response, but how can I see the values of these weights? because when I run session.run(weights) I get an error of "Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_4/bias"

Comment: I am sorry! I made a mistake in my last comment. Use `weights.append(layer.get_weights())` instead of `weights.append(layer.weights)`. That way you would get the actual values not the backend (i.e. tensorflow or theano) variables for kernel and bias values.