# I increased the number of channels from 7 to 8 in my CNN but results deteriorate, why?

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

My input images have 8 channels and my output (label) has 1 channel and my CNN in keras is like below:

```
def set_model(ks1=5, ks2=5, nf1=64, nf2=1):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(nf1, padding="same", kernel_size=(ks1, ks1), 
                     activation='relu', input_shape=(62, 62, 8)))
    model.add(Conv2D(nf2, padding="same", kernel_size=(ks2, ks2), 
                                              activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta())
    return model
```

Below is the summary of the model implemented above:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 64)        12864     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 1)         1601      
=================================================================
Total params: 14,465
Trainable params: 14,465
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

And by another question, I asked here ([How to have a 3D filter for Conv2D in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992263/how-to-have-a-3d-filter-for-conv2d-in-keras?noredirect=1#comment88982429_50992263)) I am convinced that every channel has their own set of weights. Now, my question is why when I add another channel and increase them 7 to 8, why the results deteriorate?

Prediction accuracy index with 7 channels:
[image]

Prediction accuracy index with 8 channels:
[image]

I also standardized all 8 channels into values between 0 and 1.

one of the predictions with 7 channels:

[image]

one of the predictions with 8 channels:

[image]

Comment: How were these plots produced, and what do they mean?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro , PAI is the prediction accuracy index, which is the number of events in k top locations over the total number of events multiplied by total area over the area of k locations: (n/N)*(A/a). x axis is the number of locations considered

Comment: This PAI is not really commonly used in ML, I think  you will have to provide a better explanation or use a different metric (why not just accuracy or loss?). What is on the X axis of these plots? Also the why results deteriorate might not be a programming question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, after I trian the model and do the predictions then I compare the predictions and the ground truth to caculate PAI. So you mean it may be PAI that deteriorate not the loss function itself?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I added more photos to the questions. Thanks!