# How to calculate numbers of parameters in CNN model with BatchNormaliztion

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have this model[image: Keras CNN Model]

Can anyone please explain how to calculate numbers of parameters in each layer and why "conv2d_3" layer has 18464 parameters.[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50700953/2099607) might answer part of your question.

Comment: As for the BatchNormalization layer: it has 4 parameters and it is applied over the last axis, so overall it has `4 * dimension_of_last_axis` parameters.

Comment: How did conv2d_3 got 18464 parameters @today

Comment: Did you read the answer I referred to? It has been mentioned there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @today mention, you should check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700307/cnn-keras-how-many-weights-will-be-trained/50700953#50700953) first.

`conv_3d`: 18464 = 32*3*3*64(convolutional kernel)+32(bias per activation)

`batch_normalization_1`: 128 = 32 * 4

I believe that two parameters in the batch normalization layer are non-trainable. Therefore 64 parameters from `bn_1` and 128 parameters from `bn_2` are the 192 `non-trainable params` at the end.